# How to remove a text from multiple HTML files in one go?

Tags: html

We have implemented around 180 different HTML files. There's one thing common in each file i.e. an email address. But today we came to know that we need to remove that email address from each file. Is there any efficient way that we can remove that email address from all those files once in a go? I really do not want to open up each file one by one and remove that email address from all the files in 180 attempts, really inefficient.

Comment: you can use textcrawler: http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: These are simple HTML files, we are using them just to show some animations in our android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NotePad++ to 'Find in files', this will scan search criteria (and replace the search string, if specified) in a pointed directory. You can easily overwrite the email address by an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, by using the **Windows Power Shell.**

*Navigate* to the *root directory* of your HTML Files,

and place the following command:

```
foreach($youroldhtml in (dir -r -i *.html -force)) { $yournewhtml = gc $youroldhtml| where { $_ -notlike "*your email adress goes here*" }; sc $youroldhtml $yournewhtml}
```

EDIT:

Of course you have to replace `your email adress goes here` with the email you want to remove.